# RegEx compiled with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: javascript, regex, rfc2822

I am having a problem with SwiftMailer rejecting e-mails containing dots either in the beginning or ending of the address (similarly to multiple dots inside). I would like to make my app noticing about such issues.

What should be the regular expression to filter out wrong e-mail addresses? (by wrong I mean those which are not compiled with the whole standard)

Comment: [Answer from "Using a regular expression to validate an email address"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/626273)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 1):

```
function check(mail) {
  return !mail.match(/^\.|\.$/);
}
check('amshaegar@example.org'); // true
check('amshaegar@example.org.'); // false
check('.amshaegar@example.org'); // false
```

The function check expects a mail address as a String and checks if there is **no** dot(.) at the beginning or end.

For detecting multiple dots(...) as well your function would look like this:

```
function check(mail) {
  return !mail.match(/^\.|\.{2,}|\.$/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will find a dot at the beginning of a string or at the end of a string...

```
^\.|\.$
```

Comment: Thanks. What I am also wondering about is what would be the whole RegEx being complied with the RFC 2822 3.6.2.

Comment: This regular expression is inefficient, no need to match the rest of the expression.